# Why can't I link my Stack Overflow profile with Careers

Tags: support, stack-overflow, jobs

It says in my profile that I do not have a Careers account, but I do.

Comment: Can we have proof that you have a Careers Account?

Comment: Duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/253459/259198

Comment: @PythonMaster here it is https://careers.stackoverflow.com/users/info/97833

Comment: You need to set it to public, it's private by default.

Comment: It's public already